# Como dividir os dataframes de uma lista com base em uma variável de grupo, comum em todos eles?

Tags: r, split

Tenho uma lista com *n* dataframes. Eles tem uma variável em comum, chamada `group`. Quero analisar os dataframes **apenas** com os grupos `a` e `c` de `group`.

Meu objetivo: retornar, dentro da lista, estes dataframes apenas com estas linhas selecionadas, com base em `group`.

Segue exemplo reproduzível (`dput`) para auxílio na resposta:

```
mylist=list(structure(list(number = c(26.1218564352021, 40.3910428239033, 
29.2942556878552, 45.1165094505996, 26.7251219204627, 45.9554967121221, 
47.5653750263155, 43.1406186055392, 47.4260813184083, 23.5751851135865
), group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L
), .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-10L)), structure(list(number = c(47.6476960512809, 22.61412369553, 
48.3788266661577, 48.4475369821303, 41.6704738186672, 23.7482307478786, 
28.8278631540015, 30.1230939105153, 27.1230523264967, 49.5825876342133, 
40.2128369128332, 40.5727856047451, 48.3333457401022, 22.921603335999, 
25.0721591082402), group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c", 
"d", "e"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L)))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Você pode aplicar a função `filter` do pacote `dplyr` dentro de um `lapply`

```
lapply(mylist, dplyr::filter, group %in% c("a", "c"))
```

`lapply` vai aplicar a função `filter`, com os argumentos específicos: selecionar os grupos `a` e `c` e retornar um objeto do mesmo tipo que o `mylist`.

Comment: Grato pela resposta, @Rafael. Mas, e se eu precisasse fazer isso para duas variáveis: `group1` e `group2`? Por exemplo, se quisesse dividir os dataframes em **idade** (maior de 30 anos) e **sexo** (feminino) dentro da lista?

Comment: Caso você tenha mais alguma variável que queira filtrar, você pode utilizar o comando `&`, da seguinte forma: `lapply(mylist, dplyr::filter, group %in% c("a", "c") & sexo == "F")` ou separar por vírgula: `lapply(mylist, dplyr::filter, group %in% c("a", "c"), sexo == "F")`

Comment: E se eu quiser procurar pelo valor/ palavra parcial? Por exemplo, ao invés de `masculino`, digitar `masc` para filtrar tudo que tem esta partícula.

Comment: `lapply(mylist, dplyr::filter, group == "a", number > 40, stringr::str_detect(sexo, "Fem"))`

Answer (score 5):

Aplicando `subset` com múltiplos critérios:

```
lapply(mylist, subset, (group == 'a' | group == 'c') & number > 40)

[[1]]
    number group
2 40.39104     a
7 47.56538     c
8 43.14062     c
9 47.42608     c

[[2]]
    number group
1  47.64770     a
3  48.37883     a
10 49.58259     c
```