# Problemas com filter() do dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Oi, gente.

Bom, eu fui tentar replicar um código que fiz no computador do trabalho no meu notebook. Em determinado momento, eu faço uma filtragem de dados com o `dplyr` utilizando os sinais `"<"` e `">"`. Quando fiz o código no meu notebook, a filtragem não funcionou, ele pega todos os valores. O dado está assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código esta assim:

```
pilo12h<-piloexpression %>% select(GeneSymbol,FC12h,QV12h) %>% filter(FC12h>1.5 , QV12h< 0.01)
```

O problema é que ele está selecionando de QV12h maiores que 0,01, sendo que eu quero apenas os menores que isso, que são os significativos para mim. Eu uso esse mesmo código no computador do trabalho, e ele funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao SOF Português Lukas! Para ajudar as pessoas que querem te ajudar, dê uma olhada neste [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/264276/80049) que detalha como podemos fazer uma pergunta reproduzível. Sua questão é bem ampla, que tal começar por compartilhar uma parte dos dados (`dput(head(data, 20))` e a função que usou?

Comment: Veja se este link te ajuda: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/328859/como-dividir-os-dataframes-de-uma-lista-com-base-em-uma-vari%C3%A1vel-de-grupo-comum

Comment: Edite sua pergunta e coloque o código que você está usando. Dessa forma será mais fácil tentar reproduzir o seu problema

Comment: Pessoal, descobri o erro. Não sei por que, mas o R estava importando os meus dados como character, até os numéricos. Então, dava esse erro na hora de filtrar  os valores. Eu resolvi isso importando os dados como .xls, ao invés de .csv, como eu estava fazendo. Obrigado pela ajuda, ;)

Comment: Pode importar como csv mas use o argumento `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` da função `read.csv`.

Answer (score -1):

Resposta por @Lukais Iohan Carvalho:

"Pessoal, descobri o erro. Não sei por que, mas o R estava importando os meus dados como character, até os numéricos. Então, dava esse erro na hora de filtrar os valores. Eu resolvi isso importando os dados como .xls, ao invés de .csv, como eu estava fazendo. Obrigado pela ajuda, ;) "